# Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma tabela de imoveis outra de atributos e criei uma tabela imovel_atributo já que um imovel pode ter varios atributos. Criei os models Imovel e Atributo, preciso criar um model Imovel_atributo? Como poderia fazer no método store para que salve varios atributos em um imovel?

Model Imovel:

```
<?php

namespace Imovan;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'nome', 'disponivel_venda', 'valor_venda', 'disponivel_locacao', 'valor_locacao', 'descricao', 'observacao', 'dormitorios', 'garagens', 'area_util', 'area_total', 'novo', 'comercial', 'lancamento', 'cep', 'endereco', 'numero', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'cidade', 'estado', 'condominio', 'nome_condominio', 'fotos',
];

public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Attribute');
}

public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
}

public function owner()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Owner');
}
}
```

Model Atributo:

```
<?php

namespace Imovan;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'nome',
];

public function property()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
}

}
```

Controller Imovel:

```
<?php

namespace Imovan\Http\Controllers;
use Imovan\Property;
use Imovan\Type;
use Imovan\Attribute;
use Imovan\Owner;
use Imovan\Http\Requests\PropertyRequest;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $types = Type::all(); //Passa variaveis para todas as views
    view()->share(compact('types')); //Passa variaveis para todas as views
    $attributes = Attribute::all();
    view()->share(compact('attributes'));
    $owners = Owner::all();
    view()->share(compact('owners'));
    $properties = Property::all();
    view()->share(compact('properties'));
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('/property/index')->with('properties', $properties);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('/property/create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(PropertyRequest $request)
{
    $params = $request->all();
    $property = new Property($params);
    $property->save();
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    return view('/property/edit')->with('property', $property);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(PropertyRequest $request, $id)
{
    $params = $request->all();
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->update($params);
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->delete();
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Relacionamento Laravel ***N:M***</sup>

O relacionamento **Muitos** para **Muitos** `(N:M)` para o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent), não é *obrigatório* a criação do `model` dessa relação quando se relaciona corretamente utilizando [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) fica simples a inserção e exclusão dos itens da relação.

> Criei os `models` `Imovel` e `Atributo`, preciso criar um model `Imovel_atributo`?

*Se quiser até pode criar, mas, se for uma relação que só possua as duas chaves não tem necessidade, o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) já tem as operações nas configurações da relação ([`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)), agora se essa tabela possuir vários campos é um caso a se pensar então tudo depende do cenário, mas basicamente não tem nenhuma necessidade*.

Em seu caso especifico configure:

```
<?php namespace Imovan;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];

    public function property()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Imovan\Property');
    }

    public function imovel()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Imovan\Imovel',
                                    'imovel_atributo', 
                                    'attribute_id', 
                                    'imovel_id');
    }

}
```

---

```
<?php namespace Imovan;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'disponivel_venda', 
        'valor_venda', 'disponivel_locacao', 
        'valor_locacao', 'descricao', 'observacao', 
        'dormitorios', 'garagens', 'area_util', 'area_total', 
        'novo', 'comercial', 'lancamento', 'cep', 'endereco', 
        'numero', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'cidade', 'estado', 
        'condominio', 'nome_condominio', 'fotos'];

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Imovan\Attribute',
                                    'imovel_atributo',
                                    'imovel_id',
                                    'attribute_id');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Imovan\Type');
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Imovan\Owner');
    }
}
```

Para `inserir/Remover` dados na relação um exemplo básico seria:

**Inserir item da relação:**

```
$a = Attribute::find(1);
$b = Property::find(1);
if ($a)
{
   $a->Property()->attach($b->id);
}
```

**Remover item da relação:**

```
$a = Attribute::find(1);
$b = Property::find(1);
if ($a)
{
   $a->Property()->detach($b->id);
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** Se o seu `namespace` é `namespace Imovan` nos `model` deveria ser também assim e você colocou `App`, observe isso.</sub>

> Como poderia fazer no método `store` para que salve varios atributos em um ***`imovel`***?

*Na requisição terá que vir um `array` dos atributos a ser inseridos em imovel e quando gravar um `imovel` com a explicação colocar no `attach` esse `array`*

```
$b = Property::find(1);
$b->attribute()->attach([array_do_atribute]);
//se for numa edição de registro pode utilizar sync no lugar attach
//tem a funcionalidade de verificar os que são inseridos e remover o que não
//fazem parte do array.
```

---

**Um exemplo minimo**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***Authors***

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Authors extends Model
{

    protected $table      = 'authors';    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';    
    protected $fillable   = ['name'];    
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    public function books()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Books',
                                    'booksauthors',
                                    'authorid',
                                    'bookid');
    }
}
```

***Books***

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model
{    
    protected $table      = 'books';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['title'];
    public  $timestamps   = false;
    public function authors()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Authors', 
                                    'booksauthors', 
                                    'bookid',
                                    'authorid');
    }
}
```

***Inserir/Remover***

```
$a = Authors::find(2);
$b = Books::find(2);
```

**Inserir na relação:**

```
$a->books()->attach($b1);
//ou
$a->books()->attach($b->id);
```

**Remover da relação:**

```
$a->books()->detach($b);
//ou
$a->books()->detach($b->id);
```

**Referencias:**

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eloquent Many To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Fiz as alterações nos models e estou passando o array para o metodo store do controller, mas não entendi como salvar. Não entendi tambem o porque do uso do find().

Comment: Se você seguiu os exemplos, se você passou o `array` no método `store` e depois deu um `attach` para salvar na relação, é porque conseguiu salvar, tem que verificar na base de dados. Quando eu vi sua pergunta percebi que a duvida era um pouco maior, por isso coloquei um exemplo minimo. O `find` tem a finalidade de buscar um item do seu banco se for satisfatório você pode gravar as relações como está na resposta e isso é um exemplo. No caso `store` está gerando uma nova `property` após salvar use `$propery->attribute()->attach([1,2]);` para gravar na relação. Qualquer duvida poste 1 comentário

Comment: Consegui salvar no banco o id do imovel com 2 ids dos atributos, mas escolhi 3 atributos: $property->attribute()->attach([1,2]); Como colocaria para salvar todos os atributos que estão vindo?

Comment: @Marcelo ai que tá, como você está enviando, isso é um tela com `checkbox` por exemplo e ao selecionar enviar junto as informações do `property` ... como seria a sua tela? Talvez uma nova pergunta seria melhor porque está te explica o processo como funciona a gravação e remoção de muitos para muitos em Eloquent.

Comment: Estou usando um select para enviar os dados para o controller: <select name="atributos[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
              @foreach($attributes as $value)
             <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->nome}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

Comment: @Marcelo é só atribuir `$b = Property::find(1);` 
`$b->attribute()->attach($request->input('atributos', []);`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Não sei se devia abrir um novo tópico para isso, mas em relação a edição dos atributos eu utilizo o método sync dessa forma:     public function edit($id)
    {
        $property = Property::find($id);
        $property->attribute($id)->sync([]);
        return view('/property/edit')->with('property', $property);
    }

Comment: @Marcelo abra outra pergunta e correlacione com essa. e outra coisa é assim a linha de código: `$property->attribute()->sync([1,2,3]);`

Comment: Vou abrir outra. Em relação a linha que colocou meu problema é que não sei a quantidade de atributos que vão existir pois o usuário que vai cadastrar.