# Exibir em select atributos do banco e editar com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Consegui incluir os atributos através de uma tabela auxiliar por essa pergunta:

[Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel)

Precisaria agora que o que foi setado nessa tabela auxiliar venha selecionado no form de editar

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Imovan\Http\Controllers;
use Imovan\Property;
use Imovan\Type;
use Imovan\Attribute;
use Imovan\Owner;
use Imovan\Http\Requests\PropertyRequest;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $types = Type::all(); //Passa variaveis para todas as views
    view()->share(compact('types')); //Passa variaveis para todas as views
    $attributes = Attribute::all();
    view()->share(compact('attributes'));
    $owners = Owner::all();
    view()->share(compact('owners'));
    $properties = Property::all();
    view()->share(compact('properties'));
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('/property/index')->with('properties', $properties);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('/property/create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(PropertyRequest $request)
{
    //dd($request);
    $params = $request->all();
    $property = new Property($params);
    $property->save();
    $property->attribute()->attach($request->input('atributos', []));
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $property = Property::with('attribute')->find($id);
    return view('/property/edit')->with('property', $property);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(PropertyRequest $request, $id)
{
    $params = $request->all();
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->attribute()->sync($request->input('atributos', []));
    $property->update($params);
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->delete();
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
}
```

Select:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Atributos</label>
    <select name="atributos[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
      @foreach($attributes as $value)
        <option {{$property->atributo == $value->id ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="{{ $value->id }}">{{$value->nome}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você não conseguiu resolver esse problema de alteração quando os atributos vem para edição?

Comment: Qual o seu email?

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte:

o blade

```
select: {{ Form::select('atributos[]', $attributes, $property->attribute->lists('chave estrangeira de atributos na tabela pivot'), ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

o edit():

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $property = Property::with('attribute')->find($id);
    $attributes = Attribute::lists('name', 'id');
    return view('/property/edit', ['property' => $property, 'attributes' => $attributes]);
}
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

Comment: que versão do laravel ta usando?

Comment: Consegui fazer com que funcionasse colocando o controller conforme está acima. A unica coisa que falta é que no form de editar apareça selecionado o que esta setado no banco

Comment: isso que faz selecionar: `$property->attribute->lists('chave estrangeira de atributos na tabela pivot')`

Comment: Qual seria essa tabela pivot? O lists esta dando o erro acima. O laravel é o 5.3. Dei um dd($property) antes de retornar a view do editar e os parametros vindos do banco já estão corretos. Não seria somente no foreach do blade que deveria alterar?

Comment: no 5.3 mudou, troca o `lists()` por `**all()->pluck('name', 'id')->all()**`.

Comment: Coloquei dessa forma, mas não deu certo:     public function edit($id)
    {
        $property = Property::with('attribute')->find($id);
        $property->attribute->pluck('id_imovel', 'id_atributo');
        $property->all();
        return view('/property/edit')->with('property', $property);
    }

Comment: `public function edit($id)
{
    $property = Property::with('attribute')->find($id);
    $attributes = Attribute::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    return view('/property/edit', ['property' => $property, 'attributes' => $attributes]);
}`

Comment: ErrorException in fc19f02995d308d94a071f0bad6cbf62125b051e.php line 237:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/imovan/resources/views/property/edit.blade.php)

Comment: Será que so mexendo no foreach do edit não daria certo? Porque os atributos estão sendo passado para o form

Comment: e na view: `{{ Form::select('atributos[]', $attributes, $property->attribute->all()->pluck('id')->all(), ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}`

Comment: Mas isso é algum plugin do laravel?

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

Comment: Não tem como fazer somente alterando o foreach sem ter que usar isso e mexer no controller?