# Erro SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' projeto laravel, tabela com duas chaves estrangeiras

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Função no controller para votação de projetos possui duas chaves estrangeiras, `user_id` e `projeto_idProjeto`, segue função:

```
public function votar($id){    
        $usuario = Auth::user()->id;
        $votoss = Votos::where('projeto_idProjeto','=',$id)->where('users_id','=',$usuario)->first();
        if($votoss == null) {
           Votos::create([
          'users_id' => $usuario,
          'projeto_idProjeto' => $id
      ]);
          $projeto = Projetos::find($id);
          $projeto->numvotos += 1;
          if($projeto->numvotos == $projeto->metaVotos){
              $projeto->statusProjeto = 1;
          }
          $projeto->save();
        }
    return redirect ('/projetos');
}
```

Model Votos:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Votos extends Model
{
  protected $primaryKey = 'idVoto';
  protected $table = 'votos';
  protected $fillable = ['users_id','projeto_idProjeto'];

    public function projetos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Projetos');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Tabela votos:

```
Nome                 Tipo              Nulo     
idVoto               Primária          nao      
users_id             int(11)           nao              
projetos_idProjeto   int(11)           nao
created_at      timestamp               
updated_at      timestamp
```

Comment: Coloque o `Model` `Votos` e também a tabela `votos`?

Comment: O meu caro posto sim mas estou procurando o local para edição da pergunta e não encontrei até agora,srss

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/290211/edit está o link para edição e logo após as tag, depois de compartilhar

Comment: Caraca mano uma plataforma dessas e os caras abandonaram UX/UI totalmente , na moral não conseguia ver esse menu abaixo das tags, um font cinza com background branco , ta de sacanagem,rsrs

Comment: Faboanalista se pode fazer reclamações, explicando claramente os problemas de uma forma legal no https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ ( que é o meta para discussões) , blz !!!

Comment: Vou dar esse toque lá , com certeza é valido vou editar a pergunta e depois posto a sugestão.

Comment: Erro de digitação: `$votoss = Votos::where('projeto_idProjeto','=',$id)->where('users_id','=',$usuario)->first();` o campo é `projetos_idProjeto` é o que ta na sua tabela! outra coisa as suas relação não funcionam porque não segue a nomenclatura do Laravel vide links -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel/168840#168840

Comment: Quando se trabalha com Laravel existe as formas de configurar os campos que não seguem a nomenclatura do Eloquent, mas, no seu caso além do erro de digitação tem erros no modelo porque não está configurado.