# Exibir informações de tabela relacionada - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou começando a mexer com Laravel(5.7) e estou com uma pequena dificuldade. Eu tenho duas tabelas, produto e categoria, sendo que uma categoria pode ser de vários produtos, e o produto apenas de uma categoria.

Estou listando os produtos, porem não consigo exibir de que categoria ele é.

Código que está na controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $registros = Produto::all();
    return view('produtos.index',compact('registros'));
}
```

Código que está na view(só a parte do foreach):

```
@foreach ($registros as $registro)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $registro->id}}</td>
   <td>{{ $registro->nome}}</td>
   <td>{{ $registro->categoria}}</td> {{--Aqui gostaria de exibir o atributo nome da tabela categoria --}}
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Model Produto:

```
class Produto extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
    'nome', 'descricao', 
    'codigo','imagem','quantidade',
    'valor','categoria_id','publicado',
   ];

   public function categoria(): BelongsTo
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
   }
}
```

Model Categoria:

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'descricao',
   ];

   public function produtos(): HasMany{
      return $this->hasMany(Produto::class);
   }
}
```

Venho do `ASP.NET C#`, lá eu faria assim:

```
@Registro.Categoria.nome
```

Como faço algo semelhante a isso no `Laravel`?

Comment: Se pode colocar o model Produto e o model Categoria? para que eu possa colocar a resposta do que precisa ... tem dois ajustes a fazer!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta e coloquei o model do produto e da categoria

Comment: Fiz a resposta e anexei mais algumas ...

Comment: Deu certo cara!?

Comment: Quando eu coloco a consulta assim: $registros = Produto::with('categoria')->get(); ele da o seguinte erro:
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Return value of App\Produto::categoria() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\BelongsTo, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo returned

Comment: Retira :belongsTo do final dos métodos e hasMany também igual fiz na edição deve ser versão PHP

Comment: Cara,funcionou agora. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda! Você é fera! Parabéns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta é a seguinte:

No seu `Controller` coloque o carregamento adiantado com o método `with`, porque dessa forma serão executadas duas `SQL` somente e com isso tem um desempenho melhor do que o carregamento atrasado que a cada interação faz um `SQL` para cada item trazido, então mude:

```
public function index()
{
    $registros = Produto::with('categoria')->get();    
    return view('produtos.index',compact('registros'));
}
```

No trecho da `View` mude:

```
@foreach ($registros as $registro)
<tr>
    <td>{{$registro->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$registro->nome}}</td>
    <td>{{$registro->categoria->nome}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

---

Eu gosto também de configurar as chaves, exemplo:

**Model Produto:**

```
class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'descricao','codigo',
        'imagem','quantidade','valor',
        'categoria_id','publicado',
    ];

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class,'categoria_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Model Categoria**:

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'descricao',
    ];

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Produto::class,'categoria_id','id');
    }
}
```

tendo certeza das relações, mas, também pode ser utilizadas as convenções padrões do `Eloquent ORM` sem problemas.

**Assuntos relacionados:**

- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376)
- [Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel)
- [Como mudar a palavra chave de relacionamento do laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280694/como-mudar-a-palavra-chave-de-relacionamento-do-laravel/280784#280784)