# Laravel, ao realizar uma consulta por model, como dizer que um relacionamento hasManyThrough deve obrigatoriamente conter esses itens?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Bom, eu me encontrei na seguinte situação, eu possuo as entidades Veiculo, VeiculoOpcional e Opcional, onde VeiculoOpcional é um pivot entre as duas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Beleza, existe um filtro de veículos na página principal em que o usuário pode determinar que os veículos resultantes obrigatoriamente devem conter alarme, ar-condicionado por exemplo.
Eu testei dois metodos, adicionar um count ao whereHas:

```
        $query->whereHas('opcionaisThrough', function (Builder $q) use ($filters) {
            $q->whereIn('slug', $filters);
        }, '>=', count($filters));
```

E o outro colocar o whereHas dentro de um laço:

```
        collect($filters)->each(function ($filter) use($query) {
            $query->whereHas('opcionaisThrough', function (Builder $q) use($filter) {
                $q->where('slug', $filter);
            });    
        });
```

Pelo método count, o resultado demora cerca de 30-40 segundos.
Utilizando o laço, demora 2-3 segundos, não é um tempo considerável, mas a máquina em produção está tendo vários picos.
Alguém conhece uma forma melhor de realizar essa consulta? Estou utilizado o banco **Postgres**

Relacionamento conforme solicitado:

```
    public function opcionaisThrough()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Opcional::class,
            VeiculoOpcional::class,
            'veiculo_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'opcional_id');
    }
```

Eu tentei assim e com belongsToMany:

```
    public function opcionaisBelongs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Opcional::class, 'veiculos_opcionais');
    }
```

Minha questão foi apontada como duplicata mas não tem qualquer relação e o usuário que apontou acredito que não leu meu post, o post que foi atrelado ao meu se diz respeito a COMO fazer relacionamentos entre model e isso não foi a minha dúvida.
O relacionamento não é hasMany visto que eu possuo uma tabela intermediária, o hasMany funciona apenas para relacionamentos como Cliente -> ClienteTelefone.

Comment: Como estão definidas as relações nos seus models?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei no post

Comment: Relacionamento está errado ali é um muito pra muitos

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não é uma duplicata, na verdade o post não tem nem qualquer semelhança com o meu, te aconselho a dar uma relida.
O relacionamento não é hasMany visto que eu possuo uma tabela intermediária, o hasMany funciona apenas para relacionamentos  como Cliente -> ClienteTelefone.
Outra sugestão, sou novo no StackOverflow porém leio a bastante tempo, sempre vejo que quando alguém tenta contribuir com uma dúvida essa pessoa aponta o erro e sugere uma solução, tendo isso em mente, acredito você poderia melhorar a qualidade da sua resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeZanini primeiro o que eu fiz foi somente um comentário e comentários não é resposta. Tudo bem em ser novo, nada contra, é bom ter pessoas novas na rede, mas, é bom que elas entendem que quando apontamos alguma coisa deve ser observado antes de dizer para mim Ler ... Laravel é uma das minhas tags que respondo a muito tempo, porque já tenho conhecimento, inclusive na parte de relacionamento eu já crie 3 respostas que falam sobre o assunto. A resposta é duplicata dessa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168840/54880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua escolha sobre o tipo de relacionamento mediante a sua imagem das tabelas e relações não condiz com [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), mas, como um [relacionamento N:M](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168840/54880) **muitos** *para* **muitos**.

---

[Eu considero uma duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168840/54880), mas, vou deixar mais uma contribuição que está [descrito tambem na documentação quando temos uma tabela muitos para muitos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (*tabela no centro, intermediária*) e no exemplo abaixo a relação correta mediante o desenho:

**1 -** Você não precisa que a tabela intermediária tenha uma chave `id`, somente as duas chaves que são as que relacionam já são suficientes para identificar essa linha e no caso devem ser a chave primária dessa tabela, claro que campos adicionais com valores para algum tipo de configuração possam ser disponibilizados, mas, nesse caso é totalmente desnecessário porque as outras duas são suficientes para a sua identidade.

**2 -** Configuração do `Models` ([Relacionamento N:M Eloquent Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Veiculo extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'veiculos';
    public function opcionais()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Opcional',
            'veiculo_opcionais',
            'veiculo_id',
            'optional_id'
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opcional extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'opcionais';
    public function veiculos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Veiculo',
            'veiculo_opcionais',
            'opcional_id',
            'veiculo_id'
        );
    }
}
```

e nesse outro exemplo: [Salvar vários atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel/168840#168840) vai te ajudar a como salvar informações nas relações.

[Na documentação tem uma forma (não muito usual, mas, talvez para bancos legados) fazer a relação intermediária com a classe Pivot](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

**3 -** Pesquisa

Você na pesquisa pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$veiculos = Opcional::where('slug', 'ar-condicionado')
            ->orWhere('slug', 'alarme')
            ->veiculos()
            ->get()
```

claro que esse exemplo é uma forma, um caminho, etc. como na sua pergunta falta contexto considerável, fica difícil apontar o filtro que precisa.

**4 -** [Até o item 3 as soluções são equivalentes a que estão na documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), mas, existe também a construção da tabela intermediária e sua relações de forma explicita, veja como ficaria no seu exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VeiculoOpcionais extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = ['opcional_id','veiculo_id'];
    protected $table = 'veiculo_opcionais';
    public $incrementing = false; // não incrementa ...
    public function opcional()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(
            'App\Opcional',
            'id',
            'optional_id'
        );
    }
    public function veiculo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(
            'App\Veiculo',
            'id',
            'veiculo_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Como usar?

```
$insert = VeiculoOpcionais::firstOrCreate(['veiculo_id' => 2, 'opcional_id'=> 2]);
```

Se contiver outros campos por exemplo `status`:

```
$insert = VeiculoOpcionais::firstOrCreate([
       'veiculo_id' => 2, 
       'opcional_id'=> 2, 
       'status' => 1
]);

$update = VeiculoOpcionais::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('veiculo_id', 1)
          ->where('opcional_id', 2);
})->update(['status' => 0]);
```

e assim por diante.

Isso é um exemplo claro que o número **1**, **2** e **3** é a ***solução mais viável***.

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta, muito completa, contribuiu para o meu entendimento de N:M (estou precisando atualizar meus conceitos sobre).
Quanto a minha dúvida, eu na verdade estou com problemas de desempenho, eu preciso procurar veículos que obrigatoriamente possuam (por exemplo) os opcionais "ar-condicionado", "alarme", etc... No seu exemplo de consulta o operador logica é do tipo OU, eu preciso do tipo AND... Eu fiz daquelas duas formas acima, utilizando o count no whereHas ou utilizando o laço, porém ficou muito lento, existe uma forma correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Vlw @GuilhermeZanini

Comment: Eu enviei sem querer o meu comentário sem complementar o restante, dá uma lida por favor.

Comment: Bom vamos lá eu não estou vendo a sua tela, mas, venho cá sugerir um exemplo: na tela de pesquisa tenha você um conjunto de opcionais, o cliente escolhe exemplo alarme e ar condicionado, você envia para o back-end os códigos desse cara. Bom acho que até ai tudo bem, no método escreve um whereIn('id', [1,2]) onde 1,2 é o resultado obtido na pesquisa (enviada por ela) e você faz `$veiculos = Opcional::whereIn('id', [1,2])->veiculos()->get()` essa seria a mais tranquila e o resultado já vem pronto da sua base, ou seja SQL faz o papel para você ... essa é a idéia original @GuilhermeZanini

Comment: Entendi, é uma boa solução, porém no cenário em que eu aplico o filtro eu não sei como encaixar dessa forma, porque eu realizo a consulta em um scope dentro do model Veiculo , scopeWhereOpcionais(Builder $query, $value). Além dele eu aplico vários outros filtros a partir do model Veiculo e da forma que você apresentou ele parte do Opcional

Comment: Se pode utilizar scope para filtrar localmente o seu model local, agora a relação buscas as informações depois do filtro, não faça a relação no scope faça depois dele @GuilhermeZanini